# How to read line by line gz file TCL/LINUX

Tags: linux, tcl

i made a script in TCL which receives huge input file, reads line by line and then modifies the data in some way.

the problem starts when i need to do the same with *.gz format files, which contains the data file.

the only thing i found by google search is how to do it by using gzcat and that also didn't work + it's  not good because it reads the whole file ( i think ?)  and i don't want it to process the whole file.

on short : i need to read a gz file line by line, how do i do it?
example of what i did on normal :

```
set fh [open <some path> r]
while {[gets $fh line]>=0} {
do something with $line
}
```

what i tried and couldn't understand\make it work for me :

```
set pipeline [open "| zcat foo.gz"]
set data [read $pipeline]
close $pipeline
```

thanks!

Comment: This should work fine: `set pipeline [open "| zcat foo.gz"]; while {[gets $pipeline line] >= 0} {do something with $line}; close $pipeline` -- when you say "doesn't work", what does happen? what errors do you see?

Comment: Did you check the previous conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384527/how-can-i-read-a-gzipped-file-in-tcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Tcl 8.6, just do:

```
set fh [open <SomePath.gz> r]
zlib push gunzip $fh
while {[gets $fh line]>=0} {
    do something with $line
}
close $fh
```

With 8.5 or before, going via an external `gzcat` process is the simplest way.

```
set ZCAT_PROGRAM gzcat;   # Might be called something else on your system

set fh [open |[list $ZCAT_PROGRAM <SomePath.gz>] r]
while {[gets $fh line]>=0} {
    do something with $line
}
close $fh
```

You can also do it if you have `gzip` if you pass the right flags, which has the advantage of it being pretty consistently called `gzip` when it is present at all:

```
set fh [open |[list gzip -d -c <SomePath.gz>] r]
while {[gets $fh line]>=0} {
    do something with $line
}
close $fh
```

(The `-d` option does decompression, the `-c` option sends it to stdout so we can read it from the pipeline.)

Comment: ty but i have 8.5 :( 

can u please explain how to do that there?

Comment: than you very much! the second option worked for me!